# Append/Prepend certain html elements only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently creating a chatroom, and for my frontend I am using jquery.

I was normally adding new chat messages to the chatroom using .prepend directly, however a chat message can also include html, which breaks the design.

`<div>hello there</div>` was being appended as a div, shortly.

As a result, I decided to use `.text(content)` to modify the content of each "message div".

However, I also have a function that converts parts that start with `http://` to hyperlinks in html formatting

```
return lParens + "<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a>" + rParens;
```

Since now I don't add (append/prepend) elements any more, and I only modify the .text of the existing element; I am also not getting hyperlinks anymore but only getting plaintext.

I definitely need the hyperlin functionality for my chat, but I also need to protect the chat so I can't let append or prepend to treat everything as "elements to be created".

What is your suggestion?

Comment: Do you have access to the server-side script?

Comment: yes I do, but I want to handle this on client side.

Comment: Replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively, then convert URLs to hyperlinks, then prepend the new content.

Comment: And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yaq3fyq/) with what @AnthonyGrist suggested.

Comment: I checked the solution <div>hello</div> does not appear fully --- but appears as <div>hello